# Anomaly in Regex output

Tags: regex, irb, rubular

I am having different outputs on regex matching 1) when using Rubular and 2) other when using rails console or irb environment.

1) Rubular

```
/\w+/ on test string "---\n- nicidnut\n" matches "    n  nicidnut n" 
(I have shown only matched part and put spaces for unmatched string characters)
```

2) irb

```
(/\w+/).match("---\n- nicidnut\n") produces "nicidnut".
```

I can't understand why there is two different outputs and what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\n` on Rubular is treated as literal string (since you are entering in text view). But in real development environment, in a string, `\n` is escaped new line character. So `"---\n- nicidnut\n"` is actually:

```
---
- nicidnut
```

as seen in irb.